# Why is NSArray of NSNumber(s) failing to decode?

Tags: objective-c, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nssecurecoding

I have a custom class that conforms to `NSSecureCoding`. I'm trying to encode its data, write it to a file, and decode it. The class contains an `int` array which I convert to an `NSArray` filled with `NSNumber` elements before encoding. When I decode the array, `decodeObjectForKey` returns `nil`. Also, when I write the encoded array to file, the plist doesn't look right. For example, it doesn't have the "key_for_ns_array" key anywhere in its structure.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
@interface c_my_data_wrapper : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>
@property (assign, nonatomic) struct s_my_data my_data; // the array exists as an int[] in here
@end
```

```
@implementation c_my_data_wrapper

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    NSMutableArray *ns_array= [NSMutableArray array];
    int_array_to_ns_array(self.my_data.my_int_array, count, ns_array);

    [encoder encodeObject:ns_array forKey:@"key_for_ns_array"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self= [self init];
    
    if (self)
    {
        // this returns nil
        NSArray *ns_array= [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"key_for_ns_array"];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

```
c_secure_storage_data_wrapper* g_my_data_wrapper= nil; // allocation not shown
```

```
void store_data(struct s_storage_data_secure *new_data)
{
    g_my_data_wrapper.my_data= *new_data;

    NSData *encoded_data=
        [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:g_my_data_wrapper
                              requiringSecureCoding:YES
                                              error:nil];

    // then I write the encoded data to a file
}
```

```
void load_data(void)
{
    NSData *decoded_data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:my_url];

    g_my_data_wrapper=
        [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[c_my_data_wrapper class]
                                          fromData:decoded_data
                                             error:nil];
}
```

```
void int_array_to_ns_array(
    int *int_array,
    int count,
    NSMutableArray *out_ns_array)
{
    for (int index= 0; index < count; ++index)
    {
        [out_ns_array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:int_array[index]]];
    }
}
```

If you're curious about the whole int array to ns array conversion thing... it's because I prefer to write in c++. I'm not very experienced with objective-c, so I only write it when I need to bridge the gap between my game and iOS. In this case, s_my_data is a type that's shared between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem, probably *the* problem, is that you claim your class is `NSSecureCodeing`-compliant, but you're still calling `-decodeObjectForKey:` instead of `-decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:`:

```
NSArray *ns_array= [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"key_for_ns_array"];
```

That's not secure. The whole point of `NSSecureCoding` is that you tell the decoder what type you're expecting to get back, which is what `-decodeObjectOfClass:forKey:` does.

Comment: Omg. That worked! You're my hero. I'm still curious why the non-secure version doesn't work. I thought the non-secure decoder was going to be even more likely to succeed (like reinterpret_cast vs static_cast).

Comment: Glad to help. Note that you're also expected to override `+supportsSecureCoding` to return YES in any classes that adopt `NSSecureCoding`.